# How many questions or answers in total do you need to submit in average to earn 10,000 reputation?

Tags: discussion, moderators

How many questions or answers in total do you need to submit in average to earn 10,000 reputation? (in Stack Overflow)

I am curious how much work becoming a Stack Overflow moderator requires.

How much is the appropriate number? Should it stay 10,000?

Comment: This is going to vary in an extreme way depending on which specific site you're talking about. The voting culture on each site is pretty different. Are you interested in a specific site? It might make sense to ask this on that per-site meta rather than here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I am interested in Stackoverflow site.

Comment: As a note, [diamond moderation status](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) doesn't require any specific amount of reputation - it can't be bought. Most diamond mods have at least 20k but it's not required. General moderation abilities are earned on each site by all users based on reputation. That info is found on the privileges page for each site  [on SO, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you have enough reputation to ask this on Meta Stack Overflow. I don't have an answer to your primary question, though. I'm not sure what the median (which is probably what you want, not average) number of posts it takes on SO to get to 10K is.

Comment: [Less than 1 question in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13161/mattshane?tab=profile).

Comment: Reputation (and the privileges tied to them) are a side effect of quality questions and answers. It's proof that you are willing to learn (through your questions) and probably know what you're talking about (through your answers). If you're approaching asking/answering here solely as a means to earn rep to get higher privileges, you're doing it wrong. Reputation comes to those that put in the effort first :)

Comment: Rather than reputation to become, I'd say you need a long track record of active, quality participation in enforcement of rules/standards (the use of review queues and edits and meta) to become a moderator. You'll need a few good answers to get the rep for many of those privileges, but not much. Note that rather than the number of posts, you should think of the posts' quality (though sometimes it's actually popularity). For example, on my site of main activity, there's someone with over 10 times the number of posts but same rep as me, and another with half the number of posts, but same rep.

Comment: @BhargavRao - That heap of stack is a stack of heap.

Comment: @BhargavRao--Yes. It helps to get in on the ground floor, back in the days when questions were delightfully Answered. This guy has asked exactly ONE Question: 7000+ Upvotes.

Yes: excellent question; but does OP deserve all those rep points just because he asked first in 2008? 

He's Answered 0. Questionable reputation?Just seems ... weird. Slipped through a crack.

Meanwhle, 1.3 million showed interest and 4000+ marked it as Favorite.  

I will read the Answers and Comments. I have no doubt I'll learn something for my time spent. 

So good for this guy to ask a dang good Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where it comes to pure reputation, it's not about quantity, it's about quality and consistency.

Don't focus solely on numbers. It often makes little sense.  Focus on posting the best answers you can. Post questions that are interesting. Keep at it.

That said, you might have a few wrong ideas about moderation.

Moderation isn't just about privileges; it's about your ability to make a difference. You can effectively influence a site through meta, even as a lower rep user, by making convincing cases for things that you feel need fixed. Even with mod-lite tools, you're going to hurt yourself with the best hammer in the world if you hit your thumb, and not the nail.

Some high-reputation users don't make great moderator material. Some users manage to do impressive things in a short period of time. So... to be a moderator, you need to understand the community, communicate effectively, care, and the rest *takes care of itself*.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.

I do understand that it is about quality posts. I was looking for some quantifiable variables that have a positive correlation to reputation.